# We're gonna need a bigger podium!

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics

If \$R\$ runners were to run a race, in how many orders could they finish such that exactly \$T\$ runners tie?

#### Challenge

Given a positive integer \$R\$ and a non-negative integer \$0\leq T\leq {R}\$ produce the number of possible finishing orders of a race with \$R\$ runners of which \$T\$ tied.

Note, however, that runners that tie do not necessarily all tie with each other.

---

You may accept the number of runners that did not tie, \$R-T\$, in place of either \$R\$ or \$T\$ if you would prefer, just say so in your answer. You may also accept just \$R\$ and output a list of results for \$0\leq T \leq R\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so try to make the shortest code in bytes in your language of choice.

---

#### Examples

##### 1. \$f(R=5, T=0)=120\$

No runners tied and the five runners could have finished in any order, thus \$f(R=5, T=0)=R!=5!=120\$

##### 2. \$f(R=5, T=1)=0\$

There are zero ways for exactly one runner to have tied since ties involve at least two runners.

##### 3. \$f(R=4, T=2)=36\$

- The first two tied - `** * *` - \$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}=6\times 2\times 1=12\$ ways:

  - `AB C D` `AB D C`
    `AC B D` `AC D B`
    `AD B C` `AD C B`
    `BC A D` `BC D A`
    `BD A C` `BD C A`
    `CD A B` `CD B A`
- The middle two tied - `* ** *` - \$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}=4\times 3\times 1=12\$ ways:

  - `A BC D` `A BD C` `A CD B`
    `B AC D` `B AD C` `B CD A`
    `C AB D` `C AD B` `C BD A`
    `D AB C` `D AC B` `D BC A`
- The last two tied - `* * **` - \$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{2}=4\times 3\times 1=12\$ ways:

  - `A B CD` `A C BD` `A D BC`
    `B A CD` `B C AD` `B D AC`
    `C A BD` `C B AD` `C D AB`
    `D A BC` `D B AC` `D C AB`

##### 4. \$f(R=5, T=5)=21\$

- All five runners tied - `*****` - \$\binom{5}{5}=1\$ way
- The first two and the last three tied - `** ***` - \$\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}=10\times 1=10\$ ways:

  - `AB CDE` `AC BDE` `AD BCE` `AE BCD` `BC ADE` `BD ACE` `BE ACD` `CD ABE` `CE ABD` `DE ABC`
- The first three and the last two tied - `*** **` - \$\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2}=10\times1=10\$ ways:

  - `ABC DE` `ABD CE` `ABE CD` `ACD BE` `ACE BD` `ADE BC` `BCD AE` `BCE AD` `BDE AC` `CDE AB`

#### Test cases

```
R,T => f(R,T)
1,0 => 1
1,1 => 0
2,0 => 2
2,1 => 0
2,2 => 1
3,0 => 6
3,1 => 0
3,2 => 6
3,3 => 1
4,0 => 24
4,1 => 0
4,2 => 36
4,3 => 8
4,4 => 7
5,0 => 120
5,1 => 0
5,2 => 240
5,3 => 60
5,4 => 100
5,5 => 21
7,5 => 5166
```

As a table, with `x` if the input does not need to be handled (all of them would be zero):

```
T R: 1     2     3     4     5     6     7
0    1     2     6    24   120   720  5040
1    0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2    x     1     6    36   240  1800 15120
3    x     x     1     8    60   480  4200
4    x     x     x     7   100  1170 13440
5    x     x     x     x    21   372  5166
6    x     x     x     x     x   141  3584
7    x     x     x     x     x     x   743
```

---

#### Isomorphic problem

This is the same as \$a(n=R,k=R-T)\$ which is given in [A187784](https://oeis.org/A187784) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as *the number of ordered set partitions of \$\{1,2,\dots,n\}\$ with exactly \$k\$ singletons*.

Comment: For cases where T=1, can we output the same as T=0?

Comment: @emanresuA no, T=1 is in bounds and should produce zero.

Comment: Can I take only \$R\$ and output a list of the answers for all \$0 \leq T \leq R\$?

Comment: @CommandMaster I'll allow that (though hopefully not just to avoid a fetch but rather to make for an interesting golf).

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
xt:Z^!"@tufm?@&=sqz1G=vs
```

Inputs `T`, then `R`. The code takes a while for `R≥5`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6LEKipOUcmhpDQt195Bzba4sMrQ3bas@P9/Iy4TAA) You can also see the examples: [1](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6LEKipOUcmhpDQt195Bzba4sMrQ3bas@P9/Ay5TAA), [2](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6LEKipOUcmhpDQt195Bzba4sMrQ3bas@P9/Qy5TAA), [3](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6LEKipOUcmhpDQt195Bzba4sMrQ3bas@P9/Iy4TAA), [4](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6LEKipOUcmhpDQt195Bzba4sMrQ3bas@P9/Uy5TAA). Or [verify test cases for `R≤4`](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L@ixCoqTlHJoaQ0LdfeQc22uLDK0N22rPh/bKxLVEXIfwMuQzA04DICkkZgaMBlDGQbA1nGYGjAZQLkmwD5JkCeCQgCAA).

#### Explanation

The program consists of three major steps:

1. Generate all tuples of length `R` containing (possibly repeated) numbers from the set `[1, 2, ..., R]`.
2. Keep only those tuples such the tuple contains all numbers `[1, 2, ...,  u]`, where `u` is the number of distinct elements in the tuple. So `[1 2 1]` would be kept, whereas `[1 3 1]` or `[2 3 2]` would be rejected.
3. For each tuple that survived the previous step, count how many of its `R` entries are equal to some other entry. Let this count be `e`. The output of the program is the amount of tuples for which `e` equals `T`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

Expects `(t)(r)`.

```javascript
t=>F=(r,q=r-t,p=1,v=0)=>q|r?v+r&&F(r,q,p,--v)+F(r+v,q-!~v,(g=_=>v?(~r-v)/v++*g():p)()):p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc9LboMwEIDhPaeYbiK7DMHmlaqVyaq5BEIVooG2igI4yKsqV6eEMjgoGyQ@z/yWfwpTXEr93fbeufk8DpUaepUeFNPYKe312CqJRgmu0u5X742rN5vD7RBb9DzD3fHHNdh5T1eDrFYfKjV7dtXjkW9c97lm/LXljI/f4S1zADKQCAJyBN8HSSBnEBMEdiIgeJgIVo3QriQE65XQriwT4aoR3V0bkawjkY2ECQlVXgiiGXYTxHfvDQTRuhvbbhAtROFkESpLsVBMe/@P2E0CN4llkji5s60a/V6UX4xlGqHPOagUyuZ8aU7H7ampZ0aoWM@Z5pwPfw)

#### Algorithm

Starting with \$q=r-t\$ and \$p=1\$, we recursively look for all ordered integer partitions of \$r\$. Whenever a new term \$v\$ is added to a given partition \$P\$ of \$r\$:

- we multiply \$p\$ by the number of ways to choose \$v\$ racers among the remaining ones: $$p\gets p\times\binom{r}{v}$$
- we subtract \$v\$ from \$r\$
- we decrement \$q\$ if \$v=1\$

Once a valid partition \$P\$ is complete (ending with \$r=0\$), we test whether we also have \$q=0\$, meaning that there are \$r-t\$ singletons in the finishing order of the race, i.e. \$t\$ ties. If so, we add the product \$p\$ to the final result. Otherwise, we ignore this partition.

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 46 bytes

```
f(r,t)=Vec(r!/(2-exp(x+O(x^t++))+x)^r-=t-2)[t]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc0xCsJAEEbhs9jNsDNKUqVwz2BnI0aCZGULZRh-Ye6SJo14Jm-TgHqA773pbYPXy83m-fVE0e6zLeQCzsfxSr7ZUatjGEU6UPRIiTkF964Z2vIJ558S8_qA0X2A16BOBOJSC2GfXdakNgJtWIKZv-Z_XAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 105 bytes

(or 91 bytes in in R≥4.1 by exchanging `function` for `\`)

```r
function(r,n)sum(apply(expand.grid(rep(list(1:r),r)),1,function(v)all(1:max(v)%in%v,sum(table(v)<2)==n)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5BCsIwEEX3PUU2hRlIxbpRS3uYaBsZSKdhmpaKeBI3VfBQ3sZIRVd_mM9__9_uMj9s9RyCzXYvsgMfA3UMohn7oQXjvTtDM3nD9eokVIM0Hhz1AfJCUAuizvUvNqJxLjqtmeKdEqej_mCCObgmfsoNVhUj4rdwbzsBUcQqL7Z4SZTyQhygX3rXhfzZAW2cJVmI8eS6AOZ50Tc)

Input is `r`=runners, `n`=non-tied finishers.

Port of [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259236/95126): upvote that one!

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org) + `partitions`, 95 bytes

(or 81 bytes in R≥4.1 by exchanging `function` for `\`)

```r
function(r,n)sum(apply(partitions::setparts(r),2,function(v)prod((sum(table(v)<2)==n):max(v))))
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(r%2Cn)sum(apply(partitions%3A%3Asetparts(r)%2C2%2Cfunction(v)prod((sum(table(v)%3C2)%3D%3Dn)%3Amax(v))))%0A%0Afor(r%20in%201%3A7)%7B%0A%20%20print(sapply(0%3Ar%2Cfunction(t)f(r%2Cr-t)))%0A%7D)

Input is `r`=runners, `n`=non-tied finishers.

Lazily uses `partitions` library to gather all set partitions, selects those with `n` singleton sets, and sums the factorials of the number of sets in each partition to account for the number of possible orders.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>21</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LZãʒÐêāQi¢≠OQ]g
```

-6 bytes by porting [*@LuisMendo*'s MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259236/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

Inputs in the order \$R,T\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//0xaw6PKksOQw6rEgVFpwqLiiaBPUV1n//80CjI) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##AUUAuv9vc2FiaWX/NcOdw6Pigqx7w63DqsKmdnk/IiDihpIgICI/eWBVIv9MWsOjypLDkMOqxIFRacKi4omgT1hRXWf/Ii5WLP8).

**Original 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
Lœ€.œ€`€€{Ùʒ€g1ÝKOQ}g
```

Inputs in the order \$R,T\$.

Brute-force, so pretty slow.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5@jkR01r9MBkAhADUfXhmacmAel0w8Nzvf0Da9P//zfhMvqvq5uXr5uTWFUJAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W96eO7hxY@a1lQfXnt41aFlZZX2SgqP2iYpKCjZVyaE/vc5OhkoqQcmE4AYrHLmqUlAOt3w8Fxv/4jA2vT/Ov//6@rm5evmJFZVAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L         # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input-integer R]
 Zã       # Get the cartesian power of R, creating all possible lists of length R using
          # items of the [1,R]-ranged list, including duplicates
ʒ         # Filter this list of lists by:
 Ð        #  Triplicate the current list
  ê       #  Uniquify and sort the top list
   ā      #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping the list)
    Q     #  Check if the top two lists are equal
 i        #  If this is truthy:
  ¢       #   Pop the remaining two lists, and get the count of each integer
   ≠      #   Check for each count whether it's NOT equal to 1
    O     #   Sum the amount of non-1 counts together
     Q    #   Check if this is equal to the second (implicit) input-integer T
          #  (implicit else: use the current list we've triplicated - which is falsey)
]         # Close both the if-statement and filter
 g        # Pop and push its length to get the amount of remaining valid lists
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
L         # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input-integer R]
 œ        # Get all permutations of this list
  €       # Map over each permutation:
   .œ     #  Get all partitions of this permutation
     €`   # Flatten it one level down to a list of partitions
€         # Map over each partition:
 €        #  Inner map over each part in this partition:
  {       #   Sort the integers in the current part
   Ù      # After the nested map, uniquify the list of partitions with sorted parts
ʒ         # Filter the list of partitions by:
 €g       #  Get the length of each part
   1Ý     #  Push pair [0,1]
     K    #  Remove all 0s and 1s from the list of lengths
      O   #  Sum the remaining lengths (of >=2) together
       Q  #  Check whether this sum is equal to the second (implicit) input-integer `T`
}g        # After the filter: pop and push the length of the remaining partitions
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 55 bytes

```
⊞υＥ²¬ιＦＮ⊞υ⊞ＯＥ⁺²ιΣＥ∨κ¹×§§υ⁻ιμ⁻κ∧μ⊕μ÷Π⁻⊕ι…⁰⊕μΠ…·¹⊕μ⁰Ｉ§⊟υＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBbsIwDIbvPEWOjpRJgHbjhNilh0G08QKh9YZFk1SuU@3ts6SoiAMny873xb/cXh230fU52zReIRn16QbYGnWMAqS13q1@IitowpDkmPwFGbRWC1zraUB2Ehmqafs0Vp20Ud/Jz7MTw82oTZmcyeMIe2lCh3@PWpdSKB4Z5bVeuuLsQwfeqCa0jB6DYGlLJl1H8kETdQiWY5dagbv0jNYMXy78Iqxf/rGY5amkpgnv8OYFPPPreg3LFAQObpRHfhsHSHOm5xsVOOf31Ta/Tf0/) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes \$ R \$ and \$ T \$ as parameters. Explanation: Using dynamic programming with a recurrence relation turned out to be a byte shorter than porting @DominicvanEssen's R + partitions answer.

```
⊞υＥ²¬ι
```

Start with \$ f(0, 0) = 1 \$ and \$ f(0, 1) = 0 \$.

```
ＦＮ
```

Loop \$ R \$ times.

```
⊞υ⊞ＯＥ⁺²ιΣＥ∨κ¹×§§υ⁻ιμ⁻κ∧μ⊕μ÷Π⁻⊕ι…⁰⊕μΠ…·¹⊕μ⁰
```

Calculate \$ f(R, T) \$ using the recurrence relation below and append an extra zero for \$ f(R, R + 1) \$.

$$ f(R, T) = R f(R - 1, T) + \sum _ { i = 2 } ^ T \binom R i f(R - i, T - i) $$

```
Ｉ§⊟υＮ
```

Output \$ f(R, T) \$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 13 bytes

```
R↕J:ᵐo=ᵐ#←¬∑=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FjuCHrVN9bJ6uHVCvi2QUH7UNuHQmkcdE22XFCclF0MVLbgZbKBgwGUIxoZcRkDaCEwbcRkD2cZAtjGYbcxlAuSbAPkmQL4JmG_CZQoUMwWKmQLFTIFipmAxU4jZAA)

Takes input as \$R,R-T\$.

Brute force. Very slow.

```
R↕J:ᵐo=ᵐ#←¬∑=
R                   Range from 1 to the first input (R)
 ↕                  Non-deterministically choose a permutation
  J                 Split the permutation into a list of lists
   :ᵐo=             Check if all the sublists are sorted
       ᵐ#←¬∑        Count the number of sublists with length 1
            =       Check if the number is equal to the second input (R-T)
```

`-n` counts the number of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 57 bytes

```
SeriesCoefficient[1/(2-Exp@x+x-y*x),{x,0,R},{y,0,R-T}]*R!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY09C8IwEIZ3f8XZyY8rbZ1EKQji4CZpthqklksN2Cg1Q0rpb48nIi7vB8f7XFu5G7WVM3UVdCkuR@uooQ5B/qKCTQ6hoM7Qa/8grU1tyLoyS2ar@OCfO7/0cb/wcxw8pihGHPqPx3JUCzENDO@Mhxxkdb1TyU8YrhAG9hRhjZCN3OS/qe2k4I1thNGaJ18CQnS2EStEKklOfHfhDQ)

Accroding to the question description, this is the same as \$a(n=R,k=R-T)\$ which is given in [A187784](https://oeis.org/A187784) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as *the number of ordered set partitions of \$\{1,2,\dots,n\}\$ with exactly \$k\$ singletons*.

Comment: You can take \$R, R-T\$ as arguments: [`SeriesCoefficient[#!/(2-Exp@x+x-y*x),{x,0,#},{y,0,#2}]&`](https://tio.run/##RYw7C8IwFIV3f8W1BfFxS2onQQRB3KXNVjPEktSAjVIzpIT89njFweU8OJxvkO6uBulMJ5OGA6RGjUa9T0@ltemMsq7N52xZFWf/OvqNL6a1X2HwWGIeMUxfr6JYJGKMxhOBy9tDtbqtEWoogAuEQLlE2CFsIzX@b2I/a@hn@9poTbcfBSG72owUMsHYhXaXPg "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")